# NGINX Cors allow origin not match origin

Tags: nginx, web-server, cors

I have a big problem in my website.

Since i moved from Apache webserver to Nginx the ads in my site are not working.

I added these lines in my website config file in nginx:

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Origin,DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type' always;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD' always;
add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' '1728000' always;
```

I did nginx reload but nothing happened.

i tested with curl -X OPTIONS -i https://xy.hu
The answer is:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Not Allowed
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 05 Jul 2021 11:14:07 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 150
Connection: keep-alive
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-XSS-protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Feature-Policy: autoplay 'none'; camera 'none'
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept,Authorization,Origin,DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Length,Content-Range
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
<html>
<head><title>405 Not Allowed</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>405 Not Allowed</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the Question, the headers has been added, why you not showing the full Server Block? Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers.